# Salary/benefits when going from contractor to employee

Tags: professionalism, salary, job-offer, hiring-process

I work for a small web development company that has been very good to me.

I started as an intern a year or so ago and have been interning over the summers and contracting during school. Recently they lost a few develops to a new startup and asked me to start coming into office full time.

After a month of coming in, they hired two new interns and placed them under my supervision. I am leading their projects and making great progress on them. I feel like I work very well with the team and even though I am quite junior, I feel I have stepped up to the "plate".

I got approached by one of the two partners and was asked if I would consider going full time as an employee - I was ecstatic to say the least.

My question is - **going from an intern to a contractor to a full time employee, how can I negotiate pay and benefits? Am I in a position even?**

Comment: Ultimately, the only answer to any negotiation (of any kind) is that you need other possibilities. You should firmly try to secure another job altogether. If a company offers you X, the only possible way you can say "no thanks" is, if, you have another job lined-up.  This is the brutal, unavoidable logic of *every* negotiation of any type.

Comment: @Fattie The OP has a simple fallback: "No thanks, I'd prefer to stay as a contractor."  Of course, opting for this may limit their options, and contract work is by nature risky.

Comment: @Fattie  Actually the OP is an intern so they probably wont be on a very good day rate as a contractor going full time from intern to FTE should pay more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach it like any other job offer**.  Not only are you in a position to negotiate pay and benefits, but you're in a *strong* position, because the company would much prefer to hire a known good quantity like you than take their chances with a random outsider!